# ios opengl render to texture get "texture internal format is not texture-filterable" error

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, avassetwriter, render-to-texture

I'm trying to render a camera captured frame using opengl es 2.0 on ios, then write the frame into a video file using AVAssetWriter.

So I created a `CVPixelBufferRef` from `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` and created a `CVOpenGLESTextureRef` from the `CVPixelBufferRef` using follow code

```
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                   mRenderTextureCache,
                                                                   mOutputPixelBuffer,
                                                                   NULL,
                                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                                   GL_RGBA,
                                                                   mOutputDimensions.width,
                                                                   mOutputDimensions.height,
                                                                   GL_BGRA,
                                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                                   0,
                                                                   &mOutputTexture);
if (err != kCVReturnSuccess || !mOutputTexture)
{
    NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage with output texture %d", err);
}

glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(mOutputTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(mOutputTexture));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then I bind this texture to the frame buffer's color attachment.

But when I render and capture a GPU frame, I always get a opengl error says my frame buffer' color attachment's internal format is not texture-filterable.
[image]

So what's wrong with the code? Am I set the texture's internal format wrong?

And the strange thing is the result video is correct.

And also, I noticed that it's a little bit slow render to a texture than render to a render buffer, is it caused by this opengl error?

Comment: hi, have you solved this problem?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem.  It shows "Framebuffer color attachment internal format is not texture filterable".  If I examine the format it shows GL_RGBA8.  And the texture parameters are GL_NEAREST so no hint of mipmapping.  It then concludes that the framebuffer has no attachments.